# Does $1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}$ have a global minimum, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

Does the function

$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2},$$

where $x \in {\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}}$, have a global minimum?

I tried asking [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize+1+%2B+%281%2Fq%29+%2B+%281%2Fq%29%5E2), but it appears to give an inconsistent result.

Comment: It looks like W|A got it correct. Look at: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+%281%2Fq%29+%2B+%281%2Fq%29%5E2+over+-20+to+20

Comment: You would want $x\in \mathbb R \setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, editing my question now to reflect your correction... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$g(x)=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2},x\ne 0$

$g'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}-2\frac{1}{x^3}=0\Rightarrow \frac{-2}{x^3}=\frac{1}{x^2}\Rightarrow x=-2$

$g''(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}+\frac{6}{x^4}|_{x=-2}> 0$

$\Rightarrow g(-2)$ is the minimum.

Edit:This shows that $g$ has a local minimum at $x=-2$ but this is also the global minimum because

$g(x)-g(-2)=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}-1-(\frac{-1}{2})-\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{x+2}{2x}+\frac{(2-x)(2+x)}{4x^2}=(x+2)\frac{2x+2-x}{4x^2}=\frac{(x+2)^2}{4x^2}\ge0$

so $g(x)\ge g(-2)$ so $g(-2)$ is a global minimum.

Comment: Thanks again @Abhra Abir Kundu!

Comment: @JonasMeyer, what is the difference, then, between a global and a local minimum?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes, one should add that $g(x)>1>\frac34=g(-2)$ for all $x>0$ and that any $x<0$ with $g(x)<g(-2)$ would imply the existence of a local *maximum* somewhere between $x$ and $-2$.

Comment: or just notice, that the limits of this expression at $+ - \infty$ are both 1 and $1 > g(-2)$

Comment: But its plot tells another story since we are working on R-0.

Comment: Thanks @Babak S., for articulating what was in my mind regarding Jacob Mayle's comment on my original post.

Comment: I think now its ok. I had forgotten to verify it to be a global minimum.Thanks everyone for pointing this out.

Comment: You are welcome @JoseArnaldoDris

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: Plots can be useful to see what is going on, but usually, it is best to prove mathematically what the graph shows.

Comment: @robjohn: Yeah, I definitely agree.  =)

Answer (score 7):

Considered as a polynomial in $\frac1x$,
$$
1+\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}=\left(\frac1x+\frac12\right)^2+\frac34
$$
has a global minimum of $\frac34$ at $x=-2$.

Comment: robjohn, of course your answer is more elegant (and shorter) than AbhraAbirKundu's, but it is my practice (currently) to accept the first one to give a correct answer (however long).  Next time, perhaps I should wait for a couple of hour(s)/day(s)?  =)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Take the derivative and find where it's zero.

Answer (score 1):

Methodically in my opinion it would be as follows. Let $ A  = \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\} $ be the domain of definition of the function $f$. $f$ is continous and differentiable in $A$. $A$ is an open unbounded set. Since we have no boundary, we don't have to check if the boundary points are local extrema. So it remains to see if the function derivative becomes zero for some point $x\in A$. 
$$
f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^{2}} - \frac{2}{x^3} = -\frac{x+2}{x^3}
$$
which is actually zero for $x=-2$. In this point we don't know if the function attains a maximum or a minimum, so we check with the second derivative and we evaluate it for $x=-2$, thus
$$
f''(x)
=
\frac{2(x+3)}{x^4}
$$
and we get $f''(-2) >0$ and therefore we have found a minimum at $x=-2$. I hope it helped to see it without a graph ;)

Comment: You have only shown why there is a local minimum at $x=-2$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course the last line of Abhra Abir Kundu will do perfectly for it. Thank you for pointing it out!